# getting transaction result from transaction module

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using Sqlalchemy and PostgreSQL. In my models I have a `Product` and an `Image`. I want each product to have multiple images. This is the product submission method:

```
def submit_product(self, **kwargs):

    product = Product(
        title=kwargs['title'],
        sub_category_id=kwargs['sub_category_id'],
        year_of_production=kwargs['year_of_production'],
        country_of_production=kwargs['country_of_production'],
        quantity=kwargs['quantity'],
        price=kwargs['price'],
        account_id=session.get('account_id', None)
        )


    DBSession.add(product)
    transaction.commit()

    for image in kwargs['images']:
        image = Image(
            product_id= # what should I put here?,
            image=image.file.read()
        )
        DBSession.add(image)
    transaction.commit()
```

in the last part that Im adding images to db. I need the `product_id` to set for the image. but I dont find a way to get it. Is there a way to get results from the transaction so I can find out what id the new product is assigned to? `DBSession.add()` and `transaction.commit()` both return `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using:

```
transaction.commit()
```

you can use `product.id`, because changes have been commited. So product has now its id:

```
for image in kwargs['images']:
    image = Image(
        product_id=product.id, # what should I put here?,
        image=image.file.read()
    )
    DBSession.add(image)
```

Comment: Why didnt I even try this for God's sake? :D tnx :)

Comment: Maybe just because when using other ORMs you got this value by commiting. No problem. ;)

Comment: @AminEtesamian why did you reject approvement?

Comment: I tried it and it didnt work. I had to flush database after adding image. you solution works if `expire_on_commit=False` is true for `DBSession`.

Comment: Well that would be mine next tip for you in case of fail, but OK. I understand.

Answer (score 1):

the trick is to `DBSession.flush()` after adding the image so the adding will be done and `product.id` will be accessible .